# nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 00000: [Snowflake][Support] (40465) String data truncated while performing conversion

Tags: r, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbi

I am trying to insert a dataframe into a table in snowflake database, using DBI:: dbAppendTable() via R studio. The number of rows in datafarme are 5000. I get above error only when I am loading all 5000 rows altogether. The query fails after inserting 1024 rows in the table. It doesn't fail if I load using a loop for batches of size say 100. My string size also doesn't go beyond VARCHAR column size. I have never seen this error with snowflake. Hoping if someone has any insight on this.

Comment: Are you using the latest driver version? I'd give that a try first.  I'd also be interested in what your INSERT statement looks like.

Comment: I am using DBI:: dbAppendTable() that is to be used in R @SuzyLockwood

Comment: @user11762120 Under the hood that function will generate an Insert statement and run it on Snowflake. If you go to the Snowflake query history (in the UI), you should be able to see what that Insert statement looks like and potentially identify any differences between the Insert statements that work and the ones that don't. In addition, you should let us know which version of the Snowflake ODBC driver is installed (I'm not super familiar with R, but I think the output of dbGetInfo should tell us).

Comment: @Hotchips I am using 2.21.7 now and still getting same error. Currently, my query looks like 
```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
  ("COL1", "COL2", "COL3")
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?)
```
I got this query from snowflake web UI. This runs fine for some rows of data but fails of some other rows of data